# Would drawing an image to a canvas be described as hotlinking if the image was from another site?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, hotlinking

If you created an image object like so:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = urlOfImageOnAnotherWebsite;
```

And then drew it to a canvas on my website like so:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    drawText(statusquote,date);
};
```

Would this be hotlinking the image? I initially am thinking no because I'm actually redrawing the image, and not hosting it.

Comment: you are deep-linking it, not hot-linking it. i thought that doesn't work anyway, unless the image has CORS headers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotlinking is the act of using someone else's server and bandwidth to display content to your viewers. Since in this scenario the JavaScript still obtains the image from their site, it's hotlinking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the principle is the same. You are **loading** it from another domain.